# How can I reduce the size of the picture onthe detailed product page on Magento Go?

Tags: product, theme, magento-go

I'm preparing a store on Magento Go to sell products for which the picture is not really significant. I thus would like to reduce its size on the product view, detailed information beeing inserted in the descritpion.
I'm currently using a standard theme.
Is it possible to define the size of the picture displayed, and how?
Or maybe some particular themes are already made to display small view and not large picture?
Does anyone have any idea?
Thanks?

Comment: I hope this link will be helpfull to you http://go.magento.com/support/kb/entry/name/image-type-and-size/

Answer (score 1):

Go to Design -> Themes Editor 
Click on customize for your current website theme 
Click on catalog images.
Here you can change size of any image.
Reference Links : http://go.magento.com/support/kb/entry/name/resizing-catalog-images/ , http://go.magento.com/support/kb/entry/name/changing-the-size-of-catalog-images/